# Intellij 13.0.2 is always on top

Tags: intellij-idea

I recently upgraded from Intellij 12 to 13.0.2 on a Windows XP PC. Apart from minor settings like toolbar missing etc rest looks fine.

However the most annoying issue is that Intellij doesn't allow any other window to be on top of it. If I open a browser, it automatically goes behind the Intellij window.

I already tried setting the "Always on top" to false.

I know it sounds very trivial and stupid, but is there some setting that I need to change ?

Comment: Bug still exists 2020

Answer (score 3):

Try to restart your IDE - this should normally solve the problem.

It seems to be an error in the IDE that will probably be fixed soon. Since there is this simple workaround, it might take a while till they fix it.

Comment: In 2024, this is still a valid answer.